# Can't find the right regex to split after the space that follows a commata

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Im using string.split(regex) so cut my string after every ',' but i dont know how to cut after the space that follows after the ','.

```
String content = new String("I, am, the, goddman, Batman");
content.split("(?<=,)");
```

gives me the array

```
{"I,"," am,"," the,"," goddman,"," Batman"}
```

what i actually want is

```
{"I, ","am, ","the, ","goddman, ","Batman "}
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate: Now post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a positive lookbehind will not allow you to perform the match in case the string is separated with multiple spaces.

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    // final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=,\\s*)"); won't work!
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+?,\\s*|.+\\s*$");
    final Matcher matcher = 
                  pattern.matcher("I,    am,       the, goddamn, Batman    ");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.format("\"%s\"\n", matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
"I,    "
"am,       "
"the, "
"goddamn, "
"Batman    "
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the space into your regex:

http://ideone.com/W8SaL

```
content.split("(?<=, )");
```

Also, you typoed `goddman`.

Comment: This won't work if the string is separated with a comma followed by multiple spaces.